# Leaflet map background tiles appear as broken links

Tags: javascript, html, css, dictionary, leaflet

Good day! I have a little project going and I need to have a map in my website. Everything is fine and well except for one detail: the background tiles appear as broken links for no apparent (to me) reason. Any and all help is appreciated :)
here's a picture:

[image: screenshot]

html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstr/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dizainas.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.2/dist/leaflet.css">
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <!-- <div id="mapas"></div> -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
              <a>Menu item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a>Menu item 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
          <div id="features" class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Sidebar header</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="mapas"></div>
    </div>
<script src="bootstr/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.2/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="mechanika.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px';

html, body, #container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
}

body {
  cursor:url(http://i.imgur.com/AySurDR.png), auto;
  padding-top: 50px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.navbar {
  min-height: 50px;
}

#sidebar {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 150px;
}

.sidebar-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #sidebar {
        display: none;
    }
}
#mapas {   
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 /* background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);*/
background: #000000;
}
```

javascript:

```
console.log("nu veikia");

var map = L.map('mapas').setView([0, 0], 2);
        L.tileLayer('/Users/domas/Desktop/mapas/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            minZoom: 2,
            maxNativeZoom: 5,
            maxZoom: 6,
            attribution: 'ESO/INAF-VST/OmegaCAM',
            noWrap: true
        }).addTo(map);

var bounds = L.latLngBounds([[84, 173], [-84, -173]]);

map.setMaxBounds(bounds);

map.on('drag', function() {
    map.panInsideBounds(bounds, { animate: false });
});

console.log(map.getBounds());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you seem to use a custom map (custom tiles), did you make sure you provide tiles for the areas where you currently have 404 errors?

You can open your browser developer tools (on PC, use F12 / on Mac, use Cmd + Alt + i) to see the URL of the missing tiles.

If you do not have those tiles and you do not want to provide them, you can simply specify the bounds of your custom Tile Layer, so that Leaflet does not try to download tiles outside that area.

Use the [`bounds` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tilelayer-bounds) of your Tile Layer.

Note that this option is independent from the map's [`maxBounds` option](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-maxbounds) / [`setMaxBounds()` method](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-setmaxbounds), which applies to the entire map, and affects the user interaction (where the user can pan to).

Comment: Thank you. I managed to fix it. It was indeed a problem with those tiles not having proper links. Cheers